# How to build JS array from PHP array and return to string?

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to built a JS String array from a PHP String array, but my JS skills are a bit limited.
I would like also display and return a selected JS row to a HTML or PHP string. Is it possible?

I would appreciate any help.

PHP part (working):

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //get data from a mysql table.
    $data = $row["sql_row"]; // string built
    echo "<script language=javascript>buildarray($i,$data)</script>";  //call the JS function
    $i = $i +1;
  }
```

Javascript part1:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var myArray=new Array();
    function buildarray(id, text){
       myArray[id]=text;
    }
</script>
```

Javascript part2:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function displayreturn(id){ 
    document.write(myArray[id]);  //dpisplay the data in the row number "id"
            return myArray[id];  //return the string
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `echo "<script language=javascript>buildarray($i,$data)</script>";` is wrong. Should be `echo "<script language=\"javascript\">buildarray($i,$data)</script>";` Note how `language="javascript"` needs to be escaped.

Comment: @luastoned: `language` is deprecated since 1999.

Comment: Yeah, but whatever he wants to use needs to be escaped properly, thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string from the php to the javascript and then use split function to create an array of letters from that string.

I would do it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrStr =[];
    <?php

    i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //get data from a mysql table.
        $data = $row["row1"] . $row["Row2"]; 
        echo "arrStr.push('$data')";
      }
    ?>
</script>
```

Sorry about my php. Didn't write in it for a long time.
Hope this helps.

**PS**
Sorry got it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the link between the php side and js side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call a Javascript function from PHP? (That won't work).
If I got you right this is what you want (to get the array from PHP to JS)

```
var myArray = new Array(); // JS array

<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // get data from a mysql table.
    {
        $data = $row["row1"] . $row["Row2"];
        echo "myArray.push('$data');\n"; // push to the JS array
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my post. The function myArray.push() seems not working. I still get "undefined" when I tried to display one of the row.

Answer (score 0):

To create a working javascript array, there is a function in php available.
its called [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode), only available in php5.3 though.
just call

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //get data from a mysql table.
    $php_array[$row["row1"]] = $row["Row2"];
    $i = $i +1;
}
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
```

to your code above: you cant call javascript functions in php.
they are called on different side. php on server, js on client.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, $row["row1"] and  $row["Row2"] are in the same string called $data. So it wild be : $php_array[$i] = $data. Once I have built the $js_array, how can I use it with JavaScript?

Comment: just put it out in your template. something like that: <script>var js_array = <?php echo $js_array; ?>; func(js_array); </script>